# GAE credentials not available on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am running a service on `Google App Engine` and I want to read some files from a `Cloud Storage Bucket`.

As I read here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_app_engine_standard_environment you can get the credentials implicitly or explicitly.

I am running the service on runtime `java8`.

In my service I have tried the two ways but neither of them works.

**Implicit way**

```
StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

When I apply the implicit way I always get this error

```
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to xxxxxxxxxx.
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:229)
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.get(HttpStorageRpc.java:406)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$4.call(StorageImpl.java:215)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$4.call(StorageImpl.java:212)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
```

**Explicit way**

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = AppEngineCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

By applying the explicit way for AppEngine I get this error

```
The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

I am using the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>1.92.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Running on local environment works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code works for me on runtime java8 is this

```
import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityService;
import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFactory;
import com.google.auth.appengine.AppEngineCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;

AppIdentityService appIdentityService = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
GoogleCredentials credentials = AppEngineCredentials.newBuilder().setAppIdentityService(appIdentityService).build();
storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

Comment: Hey @althor!
If this answer works out for you, could you accept it so that it gets more visibility and other users may benefit from it?